# Weather Forecast program

Tags: android, android-widget, weather

I am working on a project "Weather forecast" and information is given from [this static URL](http://myexample.info/?cities). I have to obtain the list of cities with their conditions. For example, when I type Tokyo, it should display this:

```
Tokyo, Japan#14#Cloudy ##
```

I have also created the `ArrayList` with the list of cities. I have done the layout xml file.

The output format is text plain:

- Each output line is terminated by a newline character`(\n)`
- The flow is always terminated by a line containing two signs `(##)`

It gives me errors:

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=6464, tid=7052
fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
```

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Meteo extends Activity{

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.meteo);

        String url = `http://myexample.info/?cities`;
        // Weather information
        String weather = "Tokyo, Japan#14#Cloudy ##";
        // Get the city name
        String city = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).trim();
        System.out.println(city);
        // Check the weather of the city: 14#Cloudy
        // Remove city name
        // Remove last #
        if (weather.toLowerCase().contains(city.toLowerCase())) {
            // Get condition: 
            String condition = weather.substring(weather.indexOf("#") + 1,
                    weather.length() - 2);
            System.out.println(condition);
            // Split with # sign and you have a list of conditions
            String[] information = condition.split("#");
            for (int i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(information[i]);
            }
        }

            @Override

            protected void onPause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPause();
            }
```

How do I resolve the invalid layout error?

Comment: Your string url is using ` instead of ", that might be it. Change String ` url = ` http://  to String url = `http://

Comment: @NiravRanpara Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=6464, tid=7052
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#

Comment: Please put code in question not in comment

Comment: @user1810737 is string url (i have write wrong here)

Comment: why are you using ` instead of "?

Comment: @NiravRanpara is this the code, enter the code here is error by me

Comment: put error with question not in comment

Comment: @NiravRanpara can you please give me an email adress or write to me, you have there my email address thanks

Comment: @NiravRanpara just send you 1 email, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change 
String " `` ` `` url =http://myexample.info/?cities `

to

String url = "http://myexample.info/?cities";

The `  in front of "url" is messing up your string and makes everything after http: a comment, because of the //.

Comment: The stackoverflow message layout completely changes the ` because it changes text to code, but I hope you understand my answer.